# Finding the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) When the Likelihood is the Same

Tags: statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

**The Setup:**

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be IID with pdf $f_{\theta}$, where $\theta \in {0, 1}$ is unknown.

Given $f_{0}(x) \equiv 1_{0 < x < 1}$ and $f_{1}(x) \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x} }1_{0 < x < 1}$, find the MLE.

**The Given Solution**

$\hat{\theta}_n = 1_A$, where

$$A = \prod_{i=1} ^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x_i}} \geq 1 $$

**My Question**: So I do understand how to get to the indicator form of the MLE. What I do not understand is why the indicator region of $A$ uses a "greater than or equal" sign rather than a "strictly greater than" sign.

In other words, why is the solution not

$\hat{\theta}_n = 1_A$, where

$$A = \prod_{i=1} ^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x_i}} > 1 $$

Theoretically, it does appear that $L(\theta)$ = 1 can occur for both $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = 1$. So I can see that the given solution does make sense, but does it matter than we are not giving the boundary to $\theta = 0$? Is there even a difference between the $\geq$ and $>$ cases?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\geq$ & $>$ do have a significant difference in practice. It's possible for real data to emerge such that the likelihood function equals 1. Then, $\theta=0\text{ or }1$ have the same likelihood and $\geq$ & $>$ lead to different decisions.

I believe the author might have focused on introducing the concept of MLE and not paid a lot of attention on this issue.
If I were to choose, I would prefer "strictly increasing" over "greater than or equal to". From hypothesis testing perspective, $\theta=0$ appears to be the null hypothesis and we need evidence strong enough to reject it.